# Convert all values of OrderedDictionary of the powershell to string line and print to the log file

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have some problems with converting values of the OrderedDictionary of the PowerShell to the string line. I have the following hash table [OrderedDictionary]:
[image]

I try outputting data of values to a string:

```
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $DataResult.Count; $i++) {
        $DataResult["$i"].Values |
         ForEach-Object {
             Write-Output $_
            }
    }
```

But it doesn't work, could you help me

Comment: The result:  timestamp  error  level  message - all of them just values

Comment: Change `$DataResult["$i"]` for `$DataResult[$i]`. If your going by index, you don't want to pass a string.

Comment: And if you want everything on the same line instead of 1 value per line, remove your Foreach-Object completely and use `-Join` after values to concatenate the values array to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code sample I think you have an array of `[Ordered]` dictionaries?  If so you should be able to unroll the values quite easily:

```
#This is just demo data for my testing:
$Dictionaries = @(
    [Ordered]@{
        P1 = 'Something'
        P2 = 'SomethingElse'
    }
    [Ordered]@{
        P1 = 'Another'
        P2 = 'AnotherAnother'
    }
)

# Unroll the values:
$Values = $Dictionaries.Values
```

If you ignore the demo data it's really just 1 line. `$Values` would be of type `[Object[]]` the elements of which are in their original string type.  If needed you can re-cast as a string array:

```
$Values = [String[]]$values
```

Or you can specify directly with the unrolling:

```
# Unroll the values:
$Values = [String[]]$Dictionaries.Values
```

Or Type constrain the variable:

```
# Unroll the values:
[String[]]$Values = $Dictionaries.Values
```

*Note: This casting will convert element values to strings as well.  I'm going on the basis that's desired.*

I'd also point out you don't really need `Write-Output` anywhere.  Firstly, that's already implicit in normal PowerShell operations.  Secondly, you cannot pipe a traditional `For` loop (although you can assign its output to a variable). At any rate, if your intent is to simply continue feeding this down the pipeline, you could remove `$Values` from any of the above examples and PowerShell will implicitly and natively do just that.